# Why program running GLSurfaceView is 60 FPS at most

Tags: android, opengl-es

I try to run a high frame rate opengl program on Android. It was no more than 60 FPS.

But it was 400+ FPS running in GLTextureView. https://gist.github.com/eleventigers/9545428

As I know, **SurfaceView**'s efficiency is much higher than **TextureView**. How can I set GLSurfaceView's max fps. Or write a custom SurfaceView with OpenGL.

Comment: My guess would be that your frame update is limited to the screen's (nominal) vsync rate.  If so, I would expect there to be some way to disable it.

Comment: I imagine GLSurfaceView prevents updating faster than the refresh rate to help with battery consumption. Why would you want to run faster than the display refresh rate?

Answer (score 1):

On Android, you cannot disable screen vertical sync so anything that you display on screen is capped to 60FPS (because screen has a 60Hz refresh rate, maybe some android phones exist with a higher rate but they would be the exception).

It may be possible to disable Vsync by using custom ROMs but you cannot force your users to use those and you would probably get screen tearing which would not look good anyway.

When you report 400 FPS with GLTextureView it seems what is measured is the time needed to render into an offscreen GL texture ... so of course you can render at a very high rate in an offscreen texture but you cannot display it at more than 60FPS on screen (meaning that the extra frames are skipped and never displayed)